# Which situations would Seq.reduce take parameters with the supertype(B) of A?

Tags: scala, type-parameter

API of the method reduce:
def reduce[B >: A](op: (B, B) => B): B

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list.reduce((i,j)=>(i+j))
```

i and j are type Int for sure, correct?
Which situations would i or j be the supertype(B) of A?

Comment: On a side note, don't use reduce. It causes Exception when the container is empty (unlike fold which requires an initial value and would not cause exception). Use `reduceOption` for most of the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using simple numeric types does not really help illustrate the use case here.

Consider:

```
class Vehicle(val wheels: Int)

object Vehicle {
  def combine(a: Vehicle, b: Vehicle) = new Vehicle(a.wheels + b.wheels)
}

class Car extends Vehicle(4)

class Bike extends Vehicle(2)

val list: List[Car] = List(new Car, new Car)

val gigaHorse: Vehicle = list.reduce(Vehicle.combine)

println(gigaHorse.wheels)
```

Here, clearly `Vehicle.combine` is a (rather obscure) method taking two Vehicles as parameter and producing a "monster" vehicle out of them.

So, `list` is a List of Cars, but you can use reduce to have those reduced to a single Vehicle.

---

Note, in your case, you supplied a lambda function to reduce and let the compiler infer the type B, which of course will be the exact same type of the items in your list.

But the `reduce` method allows you to use other binary functions as well, allowing a broader application of reduce as long as you're able to pass the items in your list as arguments to that function (which happens to be the case when the argument type is a supertype of the item types).